# Flink input rate control

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are using Flink 1.9.1.

We have a source, a process function, and a sink. The application consumes and produces to kinesis.

The input rate (produced by a simulator) is 20 events per second. The per second output rate for the process function shows 14 per second. The back pressure metrics for the source is shown as OK (green). The event count (Number of events sent by the source) and the number of events received by the process function also match with very little delay.

But this count does not match the event count pushed by the simulator. This count matches the 14 per second rate.

Now my question is, does Flink regulate the input rate automatically?
In my case, how is the input rate controlled at 14 per second?
If it is not, is there any other metric that I should be looking at that I'm missing?

Comment: How do you control the input rate (the 20 events per second)?

Comment: @DavidAnderson, we were pushing these events from a simulator into the Kinesis stream at the rate of 20 events per second. We verified this using another parallel consumer also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to force a Flink pipeline to consume events at a particular rate. By design, there is limited buffering in the network stack, and the slowest task in the execution graph will dictate the rate at which the pipeline will consume and process events.

The back pressure monitoring (that green OK signal) is not a definitive guide to whether back pressure is occuring. So long as the job is able to make steady forward progress, it probably won't indicate that there's a problem. You could examine some of the network queue metrics to get more insight: e.g., `inPoolUsage`, `outPoolUsage`, `inputQueueLength`. See [Flink Network Stack Vol. 2: Monitoring, Metrics, and that Backpressure Thing](https://flink.apache.org/2019/07/23/flink-network-stack-2.html) for a lot more on this topic.

20 events per second seems very slow, so I am a bit surprised that something can't keep up with that rate, but that appears to be what's happening.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. The process function has a bit of IO happening including API calls hence the low throughput. This was with single parallelism and 1 slot.

Comment: You can probably improve the throughput by using https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html.

Comment: we have multiple sequential api calls that have to be made for the same event. We tried async io with iterations. But we read in a few answers that checkpointing is not supported for iterations. Hence, we had to settle for a simple process function.

Comment: Right. You may want to investigate Flink's Stateful Functions API, since it supports arbitrary communication patterns (it isn't limited to a DAG). Or couldn't you use a sequence of async i/o operators?